# Show that the following problem is decidable (involving CF Grammar)

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Show  that  the  following  problem  is  decidable:  Given  a  context-free grammar $G$,  does $G$ generate any odd-length, nonempty strings?

---

The answer would be yes, but showing how the problem is decidable? I am not sure, I think I should list a series of steps involving multiple FSMs but I feel like I should get an idea of how others would solve this problem first. I assume there are a wide array of possible ways to show decidability.

Comment: An odd-length string is necessarily nonempty, right?

Comment: I would assume so! My textbook does not provide further detail.

Comment: I would say so, given an empty string has length 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of odd-length strings is a regular language, say $R$. Now, if $L$ is the language generated by your grammar, your question amounts to ask whether $L \cap R$ is nonempty. This question is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Decidability_properties).
Indeed, $L \cap R$ is context-free (and there is an algorithm to generate a grammar for it) and one can decide whether a context-free language is empty or not.